# how to keep terminal open if script ends after using a desktop icon to launch?

Tags: bash, icons, 22.04, .desktop

I have a desktop icon that launches a bash file.
however when the script (unexpectedly) ends it immediately closes the terminal.

if i launch the bash file by typing it in the terminal and it ends, it stays open...i just get a prompt and it waits there.

i've tried changing the :
[code]Terminal=True and Terminal=False[/code]
but both ended up closing the terminal at the end

is this possible or should i keep on typing if i want to read the output afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example desktop file that runs a terminal command and keeps the terminal open by loading the shell after the launched command terminates:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Keep Terminal Open
Comment=Test to launch terminal command in terminal and keep terminal open
Exec=sh -c 'ls ;  bash'
Terminal=true
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
Icon=gnome-terminal
Categories=Utility;
StartupNotify=true
```

You could also use `printf "%s " "Press enter to continue" ; read ans` instead of `bash` as the ending command, which then would cause the terminal to wait until you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.